# SuperCollider: load a mono Buffer from a single channel of a multichannel file

Tags: supercollider

Is there any way to load a mono buffer by reading a single channel from an stereo or maybe a multichannel file?
thx!

[asked on behalf of someone else]

Answer (score 3):

Yes: [Buffer has a "readChannel" method](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Buffer.html#%2areadChannel) that does exactly what you ask.

e.g. to load channel 3:

```
b = Buffer.readChannel(s, pathToAudioFile, channels: [3]);
```